# Css property of Hint (Kendo UI) changing on dragging

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, hint

```html
uiLayer.draggable({
                elem: '#' + id,
                group: "resizeDiv",
                axis:axis,
                hint: function(e) {
                    var divOnResize = $("<div id='divOnResize' ></div>");
                    divOnResize.appendTo(that.$el);
                    divOnResize.addClass("resize-div");
                    divOnResize.css("width", cssProperty.width);
                    divOnResize.css("height", cssProperty.height);
                    divOnResize.css("left", cssProperty.left);
                    divOnResize.css("top", cssProperty.top);
                    return divOnResize;
                },
                dragstart: function (e) {
                    console.log("It started");
                },
                dragend: function (e) {
                 //   var divOnResize = that.$el.find("#divOnResize");
                  //  divOnResize.remove();
                }
            });
```

When I drag the element along y axis the css left property of the hint changes and becomes equal to that of the element which is dragged . I dont want to change the left and width while dragging along y-axis and height and top while dragging along x-axis . Can this be done ?? If so ,how??

Comment: $("") seems not correct. use like `hint: function(element) {
      return element.clone();
    }`

Comment: I think `divOnResize.appendTo(that.$el);` not required

Comment: then how to change the css of element??

Comment: I mean how to change the css property of the clone of the element

Comment: I am getting the hint element from the code given above . Just that its css left property is not remaining what I had specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use options combination: `container` and `axis` like below in [Kendo UI draggable](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/draggable)

- `axis` : Constrains the hint movement to either the horizontal (x) or vertical (y) axis.
- `container` : With this hint movement can be constrained to the container boundary

See below example snippet: I took `axis` direction as "y" and `container` is parent element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="draggable"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $("#draggable").kendoDraggable({
      axis: "y",
      hint: function(element) {
        return element.clone();
      },
      container: $("#container")
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    #container {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 1px dashed red;
    }
    #draggable {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: orange;
      border: 2px solid green;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What I want to do is make a small area draggable i.e show a cursor on a small area but while dragging that small area show another div  which givs the impression of a larger area being dragged. In your example when dragging #draggable which has width of 50px I want to show a corresponding div which is width equal to that of container which is 150 px.

Comment: so eventually the draggable area will be limited to upper left corner but the impression will be that the whole area is dragged .

Comment: Looks like you're looking for close to resizable behavior with direction x or y

Comment: Yes...But I cannot use JQuery Ui resizable .And that's why I am trying to achieve using kendo drag as Kendo UI is what we are asked to use. Can this be achieved ??

Comment: I appreciate your help . But I knew about kendoWindow from the start. It doesn't help my situation as I have to move 4 divs on resizing one of the div i.e all the divs which are linked to that edge which I am resizing will be moved or resized.

Comment: As kendo doesn't has that kind of control in their api, we can do it with simple javascript or jQuery api( not jQueryUI) but i want to know your scenario. Is it only for single element or to apply for list of elements.

Comment: It is for a list of elements which must be resized on  resize of single element (which obviously takes into consideration that the elements which are linked to the element being resized will be affected)

Comment: hint: function(e) {
                    return e.clone().css({
                        "width":(cssProperty.width),
                        "height":(cssProperty.height)
                    }).addClass('resize-div');
                }

Comment: Did you get the solution, Hope you got some idea! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```html
 hint: function(e) {
                    return e.clone().css({
                        "width":(cssProperty.width),
                        "height":(cssProperty.height)
                    }).addClass('resize-div');
                }
```

This is how I can change hint property of an element . Still not sure about how to change the maxWidth , minWidth , maxHEight, minHeight.

Comment: Although I can use a container to contain the boundaries of the draggable div, in my case it is not a good option.

Comment: snippet does not run!